# UI built with Qt 4.8.4 on Win7 looks like on Win98

Tags: qt, mingw32

Qt 4.8.4 built manually with mingw 4.7.2. My problem in subject. I think it's connected with manifest-file, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to solve this problem.
Qt sources I've got from the official site.

Options of configuration if needed

`configure -debug-and-release -no-exceptions -nomake demos -nomake examples`

PS: sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Qt forgot to build windows styles. Run `configure --help` and look for available options, somewhere closer to the end there are styles. Maybe on mingw appropriate windows style wasn't auto-detected.

Comment: thx, reconfiguring with explicit qt-style option and rebuilding help.